# Which H264 Level is supported by HTML5 on browsers?

Tags: html, actionscript-3, video, ffmpeg, html5-video

I'm trying to figure out which **H264 Level** is supported by HTML5 `<video>` elements in current browsers?

Current H264 Levels contraint of `1.0`, `1.1`.... all the way to `5.1`

For exmaple - in the following AS3 code, the following level is not supported by Google Chrome or IE:

```
var h264Settings:H264VideoStreamSettings = new H264VideoStreamSettings();
h264Settings.setProfileLevel( H264Profile.BASELINE, H264Level.LEVEL_3 );
                                                                ▲
```

Or setting the level in FFMPEG:

```
-c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0
```

Also does not work (in chrome).

Which level value is supported by all current browsers?

Comment: afaik the rules are AAC audio and Baseline/4.1 and libx264

Comment: There may not be a single answer - i.e. it may be a bit more complicated if you want a complete picture as there are device codec limitations (e.g. baseline profile only on many mobile devices) on the one hand, and browsers which support third party codecs (e.g. safari will play anything Quicktime on the device can, AFAIK) on the other hand.